# QTP/ UFT: How to paramterize the action in UFT/ QTP

Tags: html, qtp, hp-uft

I need your help!
At first I open a Main Website, where there are many videos, just like Youtube.
Then I need to click one video and click "like" button of this video. After that, I have to come back to the main Website and do the same thing to the next video automatically. 
Is that possible with Description Programming in QTP/UFT?
Although the "like" action is same, but it is not at the same browser and page. So I'm not sure and need your help!

The Script of record:

**Step 1. First Video:**

```
Browser("Medien").Page("All Medien").Link("Video 1").Click
Browser("Video 1").Page("Video 1").Button("Like").Click
```

**Step 2. Come back to main page and click the second video:**

```
Browser("Video 1").Page("Video 1").Link("back").Click
Browser("Medien").Page("All Medien").Link("Video 2").Click
Browser("Video 2").Page("Video 2").Button("Like").Click
```

and so on...

**I have tried 3 methods:**

1. `Browser("micclass:=Browser").Page("micclass:=Page").Button("Like").Click`
   or `Browser("name:="& parameter).Page("title:="& parameter).Button ("Like").Click`
   I try this method to get the current Browser and Page, but UFT/QTP cannot find that.
2. `Browser("creationtime:=0").Page("creationtime:=0").Button("Like").Click`
3. `Set oBrw=Description.Create`
   `oBrw("micclass").value="Browser"`

But all above doesn't work.

Comment: Try using the object spy to see how the descriptions of the **Like** buttons differ (if at all). By default the `Page` and `Browser` objects don't contain a description. For more details read https://lanzkron.wordpress.com/2018/10/07/understanding-the-web-test-object-model-in-hp-unified-functional-testing-uft/